# How to hook into webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to hook into an external web service - not something I've done before.

Using VS2010/c#.

I've discovered the web service (if thats the correct terminology) and now have access to its methods and properties.

The following code was added automatically to my web.config file:

However, when i call the service I get an error:

An endpoint configuration section for contract 'PingTree.PayDayLoansSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Obviously, I can see that there are multiple configurations/endpoints however I'm not sure which one I need to specify. also do I remove the unwanted ones from the web.config or specify through the calling method (there are overloads that can do this)?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please remove the original URL from above details, it can be used by anyone in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose one of the binding name with overloaded version of the data.Which one to chose , it depends upon your requirement.

I can see there are two basicHttpBinding with only difference is the security. PayDayLoansSoap uses transport mode security where PayDayLoansSoap1 does not uses anything. so I would advise to go with the first one.

you don't need to remove the unused binding, let it be and use the overloaded version of the proxy.

PayDayLoansSoap12 is a custom binding so you might need to go over what it actually do.

let me know in case of any confusion/concerns.